# Python: Not able to split the dates from csv file

Tags: python

I am trying to plot the dates and prices from a csv. However the `dates.append()` function is throwing me an error. What can I do to solve this issue?

```
dates=[]
prices=[]

def getdata(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
        csvFilereader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFilereader)
        for row in csvFilereader:
            dates.append(int(row[4].split('-')))
            prices.append(float(row[2]))
    return
def predicted_price(dates, prices, x):
    dates=np.reshape(dates,len(dates),1)

    svr_linear= SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly= SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_rbf= SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)

    svr_linear.fir(dates,prices)
    svr_ploy(dates,prices)
    svr_rbf(dates,prices)

    plt.scatter(dates,prices, color='black', label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.rbf.predict(dates), color='red', label='RBF Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.poly.predict(dates), color='blue', label='Poly Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.linear.predict(dates), color='green', label='Linera Model')

    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('Prices')
    plt.title('Regression')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x[4]), svr_linerar(x[4]), svr_poly(x[4])

getdata('D:\\android\\trans1.csv')

predicted_prices=predicted_price(dates,price,30)
print(predicted_prices)
```

Here is the error message.

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-63df0e521768> in <module>()
     35     return svr_rbf.predict(x[4]), svr_linerar(x[4]), svr_poly(x[4])
     36 
---> 37 getdata('D:\\android\\trans1.csv')
     38 
     39 predicted_prices=predicted_price(dates,price,30)

<ipython-input-4-63df0e521768> in getdata(filename)
      7         next(csvFilereader)
      8         for row in csvFilereader:
----> 9             dates.append(int(row[4].split('-')))
     10             prices.append(float(row[2]))
     11     return

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list
```

Comment: Are you sure the data coming from your csv file is what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you `split` a string, you are returned a list, the error happens here:

```
def getdata(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
        csvFilereader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFilereader)
        for row in csvFilereader:
            dates.append(int(row[4].split('-'))) <------------ here
            prices.append(float(row[2]))
```

So instead of converting a string item to `int` you are converting the results of your `.split()`, which is a list to `int`, which is not possible.

If you want to select a target result from your list, you can try with selecting a particular index from the results to test it out:

```
dates.append(int(row[4].split('-')[0]))
```

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO. If any of the answers here solved your question, kindly accept them as an answer by ticking the checkmark below the vote buttons on the left.